# Obtener Valor de un Button con Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysqli

Necesito obtener el valor con un clic dependiendo el `button` que oprima, estoy haciendo con **JavaScript** o **jQuery**. De una consulta a **MySQL** genero los botones, pero luego necesito obtener el valor de los botones para enviar a otra pagina **.php**, pero solo me obtiene el primer valor, es decir, cualquier botón que oprima me sale el resultado del primer valor:

Este es mi código que genero los botones:

```
<?php while($matri_row=$matricula_result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <button type="submit" name="course" id="course" class="list-li"><a name="grado" id="grado" class="texto" onClick="enviar(this.value);"><?php echo $matri_row['grado'];?></a></button>       
<?php } ?>
```

```js
function enviar()
{
  var grados=document.getElementById("grado").innerHTML;
  $.post("notas_quimestrales.php", {grados:grados}, function(resp){
    $("#notas").html(resp);
  });
}
```

Comment: Necesitas usar clases en lugar de `id`

Answer (score 1):

En tu caso no necesitas capturar el valor en la función, puesto que tienes el evento de manera `inline` y le estas enviando como parámetro `this.value`, este parámetro sería efectivo si el elemento fuera un elemento de formulario y se le pudiera obtener su valor, pero en este caso como no es un elemento de formulario lo que debes enviar es su contenido usando `this.innerHTML` y ya luego en la función capturas dicho contenido.

Adicional a esto recuerda que si tienes un mismo elemento varias veces en el sitio debes usar `class` y no `id` ya que el `id` debe ser único.

```js
function enviar(valor){
  console.log(valor);
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" name="course" class="list-li course"><a name="grado" class="texto grado" onClick="enviar(this.innerHTML);">Grado 1</a></button>
<button type="submit" name="course" class="list-li course"><a class="texto grado" onClick="enviar(this.innerHTML);">Grado 2</a></button>
<button type="submit" name="course" class="list-li course"><a class="texto grado" onClick="enviar(this.innerHTML);">Grado 3</a></button>
<button type="submit" name="course" class="list-li course"><a class="texto grado" onClick="enviar(this.innerHTML);">Grado 4</a></button>
```

Vale aclarar que el atributo `name` para la etiqueta `a` no es soportado en **HTML5** tal como se indica en [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) los cuales recomiendan usar `id` en su lugar.

Comment: no puedes tener un id repetido, no es una buena práctica

Comment: @DavidSantos jajajaja lo cambie en los a y se me olvidó en los button jajaja gracias ya lo arreglo